# how can i make get the original layout of the arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, queue

so i've created this function as a game :

```
public static ArrayList<Character> spreadCardsOnTable(char[] cards) {
        ArrayList<Character> newCards = new ArrayList<Character>();
        Queue<Character> q = new LinkedList<>();
        while (cards.length != 0) {
            int k = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= cards.length - 1; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    newCards.add(cards[i]);
                } else {
                    q.add(cards[i]);
                    k++;
                }
            }
            cards = new char[k];
            for (int j = 0; j <= k - 1; j++) {
                cards[j] = q.poll();
            }
        }

        return newCards;
    }
```

the game goes as for example if we have an array made of ['W','B','B','B','W','W']
after i run the function i made i get an output of ['W','B','W','B','W','B'] as it is now organized

now on the second function i need to do is: given an int "n" i should find the original array ['W','B','B','B','W','W'] before sending it to the first function and organizing it as the example goes ['W','B','W','B','W','B'] like reversing it, i've tried several ways but all of them failed

the title of the function is :
public static ArrayList createOriginalLayout(int n)

Answer (score 0):

No. Once you've dereferenced the original list then it's original indexing is gone unless you preserve the original sorting order within the items in the list itself, but that would be very strange.

What I'd do is create a class to hold the original data and offer up a presentation function for the sorted data.  Something like:

```
public class CardLayout {
    private List<Character> originalList;

    public CardLayout(List<Character> list) {
        originalList = list;
    }

    public List<Character> getOriginalList() {
        return originalList;
    }

    public List<Character> getSortedList() {
        //edit: Note that your original method is destructive to 
        //the original data, so you would need to copy the data
        //into another structure before proceeding.

        //either do your spreadCardsOnTable() method here or
        //precalculate it, store it, and return it here.
    }
}
```

Comment: that is not what i meant and what the` question reqeuired